# Show data from one sheet into another (Excel 15, Mac)

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a sheet (let's call it 'A') with quite some data from `B1` to `AAA1`, and from `A2` to `A9999`.

I'd like to be able to show that data in another sheet ('B'), at the same location each cell has in 'A', without actually copying it, so whenever I modify the data in sheet A the data in sheet B will get updated automatically.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite Simple actually:

- Select where you want the data on the new sheet. This is your
  reference starting point.
- Then type =
- Then click on the first (upper leftmost) cell on the SOURCE, and then press ENTER.
- You made a link from new-sheet, to source-sheet.
- On the new sheet, just copy, or click and drag, and Excel will infer
  that you are copying with the same reference to and from the new
  sheet and the source just as your first cell link.

Comment: Just one small detail. The cells that are empty in the source sheet contain a '0' in the destination sheet. Is there a way to remove that? And another one: can I also copy the format of the cells in source?

Comment: Yes. There are two ways. If you don't need the link, just clear/delete the expression(s) of (=Sheet1!A1). Now that you can "see" the formula (Sheet!A1) or similar, you can add a logical expression if it suits you better. Right above the cell, A1, you will see a box with a small down-arrow. Type = in a cell, then pull the down arrow. Select "IF". Then build an expression. It's in 3 parts for the logical expression. Logical Test [Sheet1!A1=""], double quotes signifies blank. Value_if_true [""], Value_if_false[Sheet1!A1].

Comment: @alexandernst I fogot to use the "@" symbol. You might have not seen my comment made yesterday above.

Answer (score 0):

On sheet 'B', select range B1:AAA1, and type the formula

```
=A!B1:AA1
```

You can also, instead of typing in the formula, just select the range in sheet A.
Do not enter the formula by pressing Enter, but instead **Ctrl + Enter.**

Comment: I just tried that, but only the very first cell (B1) is copied. And even that one isn't "fully" copied (only the value of the cell is copied, font, bg, fg, etc... are not).

Comment: You are probably doing something wrong. I tested here and it works. However, when typing in a formula, you just get the value from the A worksheet, not the formats. The formula is not really a copy from the A sheet, it just get the values from the A sheet and puts it in the B sheet. To really copy everything, including formats, you have to copy and paste, including the formats.

Comment: @alexandernst To automate that, you must write a macro that updates on every change of the worksheet. That is not a smart thing to do, since your work in the sheets will be very slow, because to every thing you type, the macro will run again. Another option is to copy and paste it as an Image, linked to the A sheet. That way, every change, including formats, will be shown in the B sheet. The drawback is that it will be as an image.